# How to create string with variable similar to what template literals does in JS ES6?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In the following code, I want to allow read for a path if a document exiest in another path.

```
function isRemoteDocExist(path) {
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(path));
}

match /some/path/{id} {
  allow read: if isRemoteDocExist(`other/path/$(id)`); // <-- How do I do this?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax for this with Firebase security rules.  The rules syntax may look like JavaScript, but it definitely is not that.

The only way to compose strings with security rules is with the operations provided by [String](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String) type objects.  And that's pretty much just the concatenation operator `+`.  There is no string template like ES6.

Furthermore, it looks like you're trying to mix the [Path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path) type with the String type to build a new Path.  You might have problems with the way you're doing it now.  If you want to build a Path programmatically, you should compose a String first, then convert that into a Path later using the `path()` function, as described in the linked documentation for [Path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "compose a String first, then convert that into a Path later using the path() function". Can I just pass a composed string into my isRemoteDocExist() function with using Path at all?

Comment: You can try, but I suspect it might not work the way you expect.  Read the linked documentation for details.  Post a separate question if things aren't working the way you expect (this question you posted is about string template, which are simply not supported).